# Securing PHP web page access

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, ibm-cloud

I have a login form code (and a DB print code) written with php and mysql composed of six parts: dbmanager.php, login.php, index.php, login_process.php, home.php and user.php.

The login process is working fine, when someone enters a valid username and password, that user is redirected to home.php. And, if someone enters an invalid username or password, that user is redirected to login_process.php indicading that it is an invalid username or password , which is fine.

The problem is that if any one goes directly to home.php, that person is correctly authenticated without entering any username or password.

Can you please guys guide me in order to secure that home.php only for the users in the DB ?

Thanks in advance!! I really appreciate your help!

My DB is composed of four columns: Username, Password, Last Name and First Name.

This is my code:

**dbmanager.php**

```
<?php
class DBManager{

  function getConnection(){

    $services = getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
    $services_json = json_decode($services,true);
    $mysql_config = $services_json["mysql-5.5"][0]["credentials"];

    $db = $mysql_config["name"];
    $host = $mysql_config["host"];
    $port = $mysql_config["port"];
    $username = $mysql_config["user"];
    $password = $mysql_config["password"];

    $conn = mysql_connect($host . ':' . $port, $username, $password);

    if(! $conn ){
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db($db);
    return $conn;
  }
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  require 'user.php';
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DB Query PHP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>SAMPLE PHP SITE</p>
    <p>Contents of table User:</p>
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
      </tr>
    <?php 
      //refer to user.php for the implementation of the class User 
      $user_list = (new User())->selectAll();

      foreach($user_list as $user) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$user->username.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$user->password.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$user->lastname.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$user->firstname.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }
    ?>
    </table> 

    <br><br>
    Click <a href='login.php'>[here]</a> to test the login page.<br>

  </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>SAMPLE PHP SITE</p>
    <p>Enter Username and Password to Login:</p>
    <form action='login_process.php' method='post'>
      <table border='1'>
        <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp</td>
          <td><input type='submit' value='Login'></td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**login_process.php**

```
<?php
  require 'user.php';
?>
<?php
  $user = new User();
  $user->username = $_REQUEST['username'];
  $user->password = $_REQUEST['password'];

  $found = $user->checkLogin();

  if ($found){//redirect to home page
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['current_user']=$user;

    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
  }else{//invalid username and password
    echo "Invalid username/password.  Click <a href='login.php'>[here]</a> to login again.<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "You may also click <a href='index.php'>[here]</a> to see the list of usernames and passwords.<br>";
  }
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
  require 'user.php';
?>

    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>SAMPLE PHP SITE</p>
        <p>
          You have successfully logged in 

          <?php
            session_start();

            $user = $_SESSION['current_user'];

            echo $user->firstname.' '.$user->lastname.'.';
          ?>
        </p>

        <p>This is your home page.</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**user.php**

```
<?php
  require 'dbmanager.php';
?>
<?php
class User{

  var $username;
  var $password;
  var $lastname;
  var $firstname;

  function checkLogin(){
    $dbm = new DBManager();
    $conn = $dbm->getConnection();

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($this->username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($this->password);

    $sql_stmt = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";


    //place in retval result of the SQL query
    $retval = mysql_query($sql_stmt, $conn);

    //check if SQL query is successful
    if(! $retval ){
      mysql_close($conn);
      die('Could not read User table: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $found = false;
    //get first retrieved row from retval
    if ($dbfield = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)) {
      $found = true;

      //initialize fields of this object with the columns retrieved from the query
      $this->username = $dbfield['username'];
      $this->password = $dbfield['password'];
      $this->lastname = $dbfield['lastname'];
      $this->firstname = $dbfield['firstname'];
    }

    return $found;
  }

  function selectAll(){
    $dbm = new DBManager();
    $conn = $dbm->getConnection();

    $sql_stmt = "SELECT * FROM User";

    //place in retval result of the SQL query
    $retval = mysql_query($sql_stmt, $conn);

    //check if SQL query is successful
    if(! $retval ){
      mysql_close($conn);
      die('Could not read User table: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //create an empty array that will eventually contain the list of users
    $user_list=array();


    //iterate each row in retval
    while ($dbfield = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)) {
      //instantiate a user object
      $user = new User();      

      //initialize fields of user object with the columns retrieved from the query
      $user->username = $dbfield['username'];
      $user->password = $dbfield['password'];
      $user->lastname = $dbfield['lastname'];
      $user->firstname = $dbfield['firstname'];

      //add the user object in the array
      $user_list[] = $user;
    }


    mysql_close($conn);

    //return the array
    return $user_list;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: use the state of your `$_SESSION` array to test if the user has logged in correctly or not.

Answer (score 3):

Every single one of your "secure" pages needs to have user authentication/validation stuff.

That can be something as simple as:

whatever.php:

```
<?php
include("usercheck.php");
?>

page stuff here...
```

usercheck.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) { 
   header('Location: login.php');
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer!

I just created a usercheck.php file with the code you provide me and then include it into the home.php file but is not working for me :-S I dont know if I missundertand what you explained to me! Please correct me and thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you change `!$_SESSION['logged_in']` to `!isset($_SESSION['current_user'])` to accomodate your code? This is just an example, don't copy it blindly.

Comment: I changed the logged_in for current_user before but didnt add the !isset, but now it works!!! thanks my friend!!!

Answer (score -1):

Basically you have to create a lib directory in your local directory structure and all files in lib will not be public available, but you can still access them from inside your php application.

Here is an example of the file structure for PHP application in cloud foundry:

```
alexs-mbp:ads-php-test adasilva$ ls -l
total 72
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff   490 Sep 14 23:00 README.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff   990 Sep 14 19:09 checklogin.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff     2 Sep 14 23:00 composer.json
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 adasilva  staff   102 Sep 14 19:01 images
drwxr-xr-x  3 adasilva  staff   102 Sep 14 19:14 includes
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff   709 Sep 14 23:00 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 adasilva  staff    68 Sep 15 17:41 lib
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff   261 Sep 14 19:09 loginsuccess.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff    88 Sep 14 19:11 logout.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff   809 Sep 14 19:08 main_login.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff   193 Sep 14 23:00 manifest.yml
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adasilva  staff  1157 Sep 14 23:00 style.css
alexs-mbp:ads-php-test adasilva$
```

Anything under lib directory will not be publicly exposed, so you may put your home.php file there.

See more details here:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-usage.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I just did that but, in the login_process.php where I redirect to home.php I changed header("Location: home.php"); for header("Location: lib/home.php"); but is not working properly, can you please tell me what am I doing wrong ??


if ($found){//redirect to home page
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['current_user']=$user;

    header("Location: lib/home.php");
    exit;